# I am having a problem with the module mp3play

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, syntax-error, python-module

```
import mp3play
import time

loc=r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Francisco\music.mp3'
tocar=mp3play.load(loc)

tocar.play()

time.sleep(10)
```

I used this code to try to play an mp3 file on my computer but I received an error.

The error was saying this:

```
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Francisco\pen\projetos\projeto2 2023\ex020.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mp3play
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Francisco\pen\projetos\projeto2 2023\.venv\Lib\site-packages\mp3play\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .windows import AudioClip as _PlatformSpecificAudioClip
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Francisco\pen\projetos\projeto2 2023\.venv\Lib\site-packages\mp3play\windows.py", line 27
    print 'Error %s for "%s": %s' % (str(err), txt, buf)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
```

I´ve imported this module from PyPI in the official site of python, if you want to check the project for yourself, the project name is mp3play 0.1.15

Thank you all.

Comment: It seems to be an old and apparently unmaintained package designed for Python 2, in Python 3 `print` is a function and this is the cause of the error. Either you adapt the code to Python 3 (which may or may not be simple, I haven't looked at the source code) or you look for an alternative. Depending on what you want to do with the audio, playsound  or Pydub/Pyaudio may work.

Comment: Thanks,  now I am using pygame and I solved my problem